# How can I create this graph in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, differential-geometry, topology

I'm interested in illustrating a hyperbolic plane for a report I'm writing.  Here's the metric that I'm using:

$$ds^2=dr^2+\sqrt{\lvert k\rvert}^{-1}\sinh\left(r\sqrt{\lvert k\rvert}\right)\left( d\theta^2+\sin^2\theta\space d\phi^2 \right)$$

And I'd like it to look like this:

[image: surface]

Marco's answer below is a good start:

```
Plot3D[Sinh[x] Sinh[y], {x, y} \[Element] Disk[], BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

I'd like to do basically this, but using radial coordinates (like in the picture).

Comment: ... and what have you tried? It would seem to me that a Plot3D with an appropriate RegionFunction (a disk?), or using the newer Element[{x, y}, region] to specify the support of your lot could help.

Comment: I was thinking of something like `Plot3D[Sinh[x] Sinh[y], {x, y} \[Element] Disk[], BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]` plus appropriate formatting modifications.

Comment: @MarcoB He may mean to use differential geometry to solve this problem.  For example, using `FrenetSerretSystem` function.

Comment: @MarcoB - That looks like a good start.  Is it possible to do the same thing with radial coordinates (like in the plot)?  Write it up as an answer and I'll up-vote it.

Comment: @Quarkly I'd be happy to if the question gets reopened. In any case, the special sauce to get the polar-style gridlines would be `MeshFunctions -> {Norm[{#1, #2}] &, ArcTan[#1, #2] &}`. Give me a ping if the question gets reopened and I'll write a proper answer.

Comment: You're one of the people who closed it.  Perhaps if you reopen it, the other people who closed it will reconsider.

Comment: @Quarkly, Yes, I have already voted to reopen it.

Comment: @MarcoB - Yes!  That's it.  That's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Quarkly Added an answer now the question has been reopened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the approach I teased in comments:

```
Plot3D[
  Sinh[x] Sinh[y], {x, y} ∈ Disk[],
  MeshFunctions -> {Norm[{#1, #2}] &, ArcTan[#1, #2] &}, 
  Mesh -> {15, 40},
  MeshStyle -> Black,
  PlotPoints -> 75,
  PlotTheme -> {"Classic"},
  Background -> Black,
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False,
  ViewPoint -> {3, -1, 2}, ViewVertical -> {-0.5, 0.2, 1}
]
```

[image: 3D plot with black background no axes no frames]

Comment: Exactly what I needed.